# Tags on documents are searchable but not visible

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, tagging, mms

One of my 2013 sites has an MMS system set up for tagging images in a document library. It was functioning perfectly for months while one of our co-ops was working to tag everything in the library. But just recently the tags stopped showing up when viewing/editing any document. The weird thing is they are still searchable, but when you look at the document the tags field is blank. It still registers that it was edited by the user, and when editing the document you can add tags, but they don't show up after it is saved.

Another odd part about it is that when you search for a document by one of its tags, it gives the message "Your search returned no results. Some files might be hidden. [Include] these in your search." Once you click "Include" the results appear normally. This only affects searching for tags, not for any other property of the documents. I'm assuming this is related, but I don't know where to start troubleshooting it.

Comment: Are you talking about Enterprise Keywords by any chance?
We had the same thing happen with EK. Turned out to be a weird permissions thing on a hidden library that maintains the EK tags.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but is that the same as Managed Metadata? Do you have a link to instructions for fixing it, or could you describe the solution you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to this URL: [site collection URL]/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx

This is where the Managed Metadata terms actually get stored when "used", rather than actually referencing the physical MMS.

Permissions here may have been modified so that users cannot read the actual values.

Comment: Yup behind the scenes Managed Metadata columns are derived from Lookups. They're Lookups to the TaxonomyHiddenList.. So OP's problem does indeed look like a permission mishap with that list.

Comment: Yup, I'm guessing that's it. There were zero permissions listed there (which makes me wonder how I was able to access it at all). I'll test it out and accept your answer if this solves it.